# Gravity changes in relation to different sizes of celestial objects

Tags: science-based, gravity, celestial-objects

**The Problem**

I changed the circumference of some of my world's celestial objects. How can I calculate the object's new gravity?

The density of the objects is still the same as it would originally be - just the size is different. The only thing I want to know is what are the new **G-Forces** of both objects?

**Earth:**

```
Circumference (Old) = 40,075 km
Circumference (New) = 39,000 km 
Size Decrease (Total) = 1,075 km

G-Force(Old) = 1 G
```

**Moon:**

```
Circumference (Old) = 10,921 km
Circumference (New) = 12,000 km  
Size Increase (Total) = 1,079 km

G-Force(Old) =  0.166 G
```

Comment: Circumference is an unusual measurement to be using in this calculation - radius is the more normal measurement, since (for a perfect sphere) it plugs straight into the calculation of mass, which is what you need to calculate the change in surface gravity (if G-Force means "surface gravity").  Suggest that you work out the radius that goes with your desired circumference and you should be able to calculate the "mass of a sphere" and resultant "surface gravity" using the top results for any search on those terms.

Comment: I can calculate diameter and and radius if needed. Though mass and such are another matter which is the reason i decided to post this question. As far as i know calculation of a celestial objects gravity is not really easy at least for someone like me.

Comment: You appear to be trying for a slightly smaller Earth and a slightly larger moon.  Please actually *search* for a) "density of the Earth", then b) "mass of a sphere" and finally c) "surface gravity formula".  It should take less time than waiting for an answer, and save you getting downvotes for "lack of research".

Comment: I will try it though it will be likely a day till i get to have time for it i will leave this post here in the meantime. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's odd to do this using circumference when the equations don't use it. The *acceleration due to gravity* for a single object (in which case you're asking two questions...) is g=GM/r^2. (G = universal constant, 6.674×10−11 N⋅m^2/kg^2)(M = mass of object in Kg)(r = radius in meters). The *gravitational force* between two objects (in which case you're asking one question...) is $F=GM_1M_2)/d^2 $(d = distance between objects in kg). In other words, this is a question of basic mathematics. You can reverse calculate the masses from those equations.

Comment: Yeah this question is a little bit the fault of my incompetence and won't probably occur again. Though this also partially as my world does not really require a lot of such calculations at least those i am unable to solve my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two important gravitation factors of a fictional planet, escepcially a habitable one, are its surface gravity and its escape velocity.  They have to be calculated seperatly.

The surface gravity will be important for any native lifeforms and for any Earth humans who may visit the world.

For an explanation see Stephen H. Dole, *Habitable Planets for Man*  (1964) pp. 11-13.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

The escape velocity will be important to anyone planning to leave the world.  But storywise it will be most important in determining how fast the planet, moon, or other world will lose atmosphere into space.  The world will have to replace atmosphere faster than it is lost, or else the atmospheric density will reduce over time until it eventually becomes a vacuum for all practical purposes.

This is discussed in Stephen H. Dole, *Habitable Planets for Man* (1964) pp. 33-39, 54-58.

If your planet is supposed to have an oxygen rich atmosphere you also have to considered how it will take an originally uninhabitle (for humans and other oxygen users) world to develop a breathable oxygen rich atmosphere.  Which means that if the planet loses all its atmosphere before a breatheable oxygen rich atmosphere is produced, it will never have a breatheable oxygen rich atmosphere.

For a discussion of this see Stephen H. Dole, *Habitable Planets for Man* (1964) pp. 61-63.  This factor mades table 5 on page 35 quite important.

Here is a link to an online calculator of the acceleration from gravity.

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/acceleration-due-to-gravity

Here is a link to an online escape velocity calculator.

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/escape-velocity

The question asks:

> Earth:
>
> Circumference(Old) = 40,075 km Circumference(New) = 39,000 km Size Decrease(Total) = 1,075 km
>
> G-Force(Old) = 1 G
>
> Moon:
>
> Circumference(Old) = 10,921 km Circumference(New) = 12.000 km
> Size Increase(Total) = 1,079 km
>
> G-Force(Old) = 0,166 G

So the Earth has a mean radius of 6,371.0 kilometers and a circumference of 40,075 kilometers.  You want the Earth analog to have a a circumference 39,000 kilometers while having the same density as Earth.

A world with a circumference of 39,000 kilometers will have a radius of 6,207.04 kilometers, which will be 0.9742646 the radius of Earth.  Thus the planet will have 0.9240104 the volume of Earth, and with the same density was Earth it would have 0.9240104 the mass of Earth.

So your Earth like planet should have a surface gravity of 0.9748 *g*, or 9.56 meters per second per second.

And it should have an escape velocity of about 10.895 kilometers per second.  Which is about 0.9739 of Earth's escape velocity.

So your planet has a surface gravity 0.9748 that of Earth and an escape velocity 0.9739 that of Earth.  The surface gravity and the escape velocity of an alien world will not have the same proportion relative to those of Earth and have to be calculated separately.

You want the Moon analog to have a cirumference of 12,000 kilometers but the same density as the Moon.  The density of the Moon is 3.334 grams per cubic centimeter, or 0.606 that of Earth.  With a circumerence of 12,000 kilometers, the moon analog will have a radius of 1,909.86 kilometers, which is 0.2997739 the radius of Earth.  Thus the moon analog will have a volume 0.0269389 the volume of Earth, and with an density 0.606 that of Earth it will have a mass 0.0163249 of Earth.

Thus the moon analog will have a surface gravity of 1.784 meters per second per second, or 0.1819 that of Earth or 0.1819 *g*.  That is about 1.0998 the surface gravity of the Moon.

And the moon analog will have an escape velocty of 2.6104 metrs per second, which is  1.0968067 the escape velocity of the Moon, and 0.2333631 the escape velocity of Earth.  And 0.9884134 the escape velocity of Titan, the largest moon of Saturn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i know it was a basic calculation and i promise not to ask such a question again.